# hash string at hash number java

Tags: java, hash

Hiii,I need to do the opposite of what my hash method does, I want a number to convert it to a string, unlike my other method.

I need you to do it in the same way coding as decoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to implement the [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher).

I have fixed your code for executing the two functions (`hash` and `hash2`) and I have noticed that `hash("javaguay")` returns the long number `2485697837967351` and then `hash2(2485697837967351L)` returns `yaugavaj`, the reverse string that you want.

A quick response could be the next, but I think you must fix your algorithm.

Add these lines to the end `hash2` function:

```
   String res2 = "";
    for (int i = res.length() -1; i >=0; i--) {
      res2 += res.charAt(i);
    }
    return res2;
```

Answer (score 2):

That would only be possible if there was a 1 to 1 mapping between `String`s and `long`s. Since there are 2<sup>64</sup> possible long values, and many many more possible `String` values (even if you limit yourself to `String`s of 64 characters, there are still K<sup>64</sup> of them, where K is the number of possible unique characters), there cannot be a method that reverses your `long hash(String c)` method for all possible `String`s.

Comment: By the way, it is exactly one of the properties of the hash functions. Really easy in one way, almost impossible in the other way.

Comment: @Lutzi it's not just "almost impossible". It is impossible. a hash value usually contains much less data than the input that is being hashed, so it can't be used to restore that input.

Comment: I added the "almost" in the case I was saying something wrong ... Thanks for your explanation, it makes much sense !

Comment: @Lutzi well, there are edge cases where the data can be restored, but they are less interesting (for example, for `Integer` class, the `hashCode()` is simply the value of the `Integer`, so it's easy to restore).